# Find $[n, n+1]$ such that $f(n)<0<f(n+1)$ where $f(x)=x^3-x+3<0$

Tags: calculus, continuity

$x^3-x+3=0$ doesn't factor, though $x^3-x=x(x-1)(x+1)$ and $x^3-x<0$ when $x<-1$. The constant term $3$ translates the graph up, and I check the value of $f(x)$ at $-1$ and $-2$ assuming that after the translation it can be positive at $-1$ and negative at $-2$, which is indeed the case. The answer is $n=-2$.

Is there a better way to solve this, or I just need to check all $x$ in some interval to find where $f(x)$ changes the sign?

Comment: Sounds like a fairly good way to solve the problem to me.

Comment: As $f(0)=3$, what is wrong in substituting $n=-1,n=-2$ and finding that $f(-2)<0<f(-1)$?

Answer (score 1):

For me it's a little easier to work with positive numbers. Obviously $f(x)>0$ if $x \ge 0, x \in \mathbb{Z}$, so let's assume $x<0, y:=-x, g(y) = f(x)=-y^3+y+3=3-(y^3-y), y \in \mathbb N.$

Now it's easy to show $y^3-y$ is monotone increasing with $y\in \mathbb N$ (via factoring or taking first derivative), so $g(y)$ is monotone decreasing and $g(1)=3>0>g(2)=-3$.